# PHP getter returns nothing despite $this having the asked variable

Tags: php

When I try to use a parent getter on a extended class, the getter returns nothing, despite XDebug stating that `$this` indeed has the variable. If I call a getter of the extended class, it does return its value normally. For example on a class

```
<?php
require_once 'Shelf.php';


class LocatedShelf extends Shelf{ 
    private $hall;
    private $number;

//...(construct, getters and setters)
}
```

And the parent class

```
class Shelf{
    private $id;
    private $occupiedSpaces;
    private $code;
    private $material;
    private $totalSpaces;
    private $registerDate;
//...(construct, getters and setters)
}
```

Calling a `Shelf` getter such as `getCode()` from a `LocatedShelf` object returns nothing, despite PHP acessing the parent getter and `$this` having the target variable. However calling either `getHall()` or `getNumber()` works as intended and return their values.

Comment: Unfortunately you seem to have omitted from your example many of the pieces of code you're talking about the in the description. We also have no example of the script you're using where you're instantiating these classes and calling these functions in order to observe this behaviour. Therefore it's very hard to say with certainty what the issue would be, we could only make potential suggestions. For clarity, provide a complete example of the problem please, such that we could actually execute and test it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the variables to `protected`.

If they are `private`, only the class itself can access them. In your case however, a subclass accesses the variables. If you set them to `protected`, the class itself and all subclasses can access the variables.

Comment: I'm unsure of what this answer is trying to illustrate. The whole point of using getters is not needing to grant direct access to properties.